# Is Jesus called YHWH in Joel 2:32/Romans 10:13?

Tags: jesus, romans, nt-use-of-hebrew-bible, tetragrammaton, joel

In Romans 10, Paul is discussing the Lord Jesus, and in verse 13, he writes (NKJV, emphasis mine):

> For “whoever calls on the name of **the LORD** shall be saved.”

The reason "LORD" is capitalized by the New King James Version here is that in Joel 2:32, the original verse Paul quotes, the word used is *YHWH*. Yet Paul uses this verse in reference to Jesus. If the subject of Joel 2:32 is YHWH/Jehovah, and if Joel 2:32 applies to Jesus (as says Paul), then does Joel 2:32 refer to Jesus as YHWH/Jehovah? Thanks!

Comment: The NT was written in Greek, not Hebrew. The former does not employ *lord* solely for God.

Comment: @Lucizn you missed the point.  If Joel has YHWH, and Paul quotes Joel  with Kurios translating YHWH as referring to Jesus.  Is he equating Jesus with YHWH?

Comment: I love this question - very clever thinking

Comment: Paul is implying that if one has faith in Jesus one can have salvation. In Romans 10:13 Paul is talking of Jehovah as being reachable, for those calling on Him, if they go through  His mediator Jesus who, if they first believe in Jesus, can then be heard. Both verses in Joel and Romans, should have been translated "...who calls on the name of YHWH/Jehovah..." Consequently, neither verse refers to Jesus as YHWH/Jehovah. That would just be conjecture.

Comment: @OldeEnglish It seems we agree that the referent of Joel 2:32's "YHWH" would be the same Person referenced by "kurios" in Romans 10:13 (since Paul quotes Joel). So let's consider this further: In the verses near Rom. 10:13 (e.g., v. 9, 12), Jesus is referred to as "Lord" (Greek kurios, the same word that appears in Paul's quotation of Rom. 10:13), and in verse 13, we're told that calling on the name of the "Lord" (kurios) results in salvation. To confirm I understand, is the referent of "Lord" in verse 13 the same Person referenced by "Lord" in verses 9 and 12 (i.e., Jesus)?

Comment: In short, 'No!' Verses 9,12 are referencing the lord, Jesus. V 13 is in reference to YHWH/Jehovah. Here in lies the problem, that the 2nd, or 3rd, century copyists caused when they substituted the divine name of YHWH (or, JHVH) with the words Kyrios, "Lord," and Theos, "God." In the LXX the Greek words have been used to crowd out the 'distinctive' name of the Supreme Deity, which, quite frankly, IMO was nothing short of BLASPHEMY. When one substitutes the 'distinctive' names of Jesus and YHWH with the mere 'titles' of lord/Lord one is to be confusing and God is not a God of confusion...tbc...

Comment: ... Hence, the modern translator is warranted in using the divine name as an equivalent of those two Greek words, that is, at places where the writers of the Christian Greek Scriptures  quote verses, passages, and expressions from the Hebrew Scriptures or from the LXX where the divine name occurs. See p. 347 of "A Greek and English Lexicon, by J Parkhurst (revised ed. of 1845), or, p. 365 of J H Thayer's 1889 edition, or, p. 1013 of the "A Greek-English Lexicon, Liddell and Scott, if you need any further confirmation, which I improvised above from pages 10 & 11 of the KIT of the GS...

Comment: ....The Kingdom Interlinear Translation of the Greek Scriptures.

Comment: Romans 10:12-13 says (NKJV), "For there is no distinction between Jew and Greek, for the same **Lord [kurios]** over all is rich to all who **call upon [epikaleomai]** Him. For 'whoever **calls on [epikaleomai]** the name of the **LORD [kurios]** shall be saved'" (**bold** emphasis [and brackets] mine). You're saying that _kurios_ in verse 12 is not the same Person as _kurios_ in verse 13? But isn't verse 13, which begins with "For," an explanation Paul makes of verse 12 by quoting Joel 2:32?

Comment: @OldeEnglish I agree that the Greek changing the name from YHWH to _kurios_ could cause people to mistake who the original Person was being referenced in OT passages. But in this case, isn't it Paul himself who's arguing that the One referenced in Joel 2:32 is the same One he's been referencing (i.e., Jesus)? After all, Paul's talking about calling on the Lord and then backs up what he says by quoting Joel 2:32, a verse that in the translation he used mentions "calling on" and "the Lord" (see my above comment).

Comment: I of course have an 'NWT' bible along with the 'Interlinear', above mentioned, whereupon, as I understand it, great pains were taken in the translations, using original manuscripts where possible and numerous other reference materials, some of which I have already borne out. They only use, in translation, the name of Jehovah in verse 13 (the ref. to Joel 2:32) and in verse 16 (a ref. to Isaiah 53:1). Everywhere else in Romans 10, is a reference to Jesus and that may be all that I can tell you at this point. I'm being told to move to 'chat' here at this juncture, which I will if you want to.

Comment: @OldeEnglish As you said, we're supposed to avoid extended discussions, so I'll close with this: The Kingdom Interlinear Translation of the Greek Scriptures is a translation by Jehovah's Witnesses, and their decision to insert the name is not backed by any available Greek manuscripts. In this thread, I'm primarily focused on what the ancient Greek manuscripts say, and my trust in a translation only goes as far as what can be backed up by the ancient manuscripts/versions.

Comment: Fair comment. If you have the time and the inclination, check out this Christianity SE link:-  https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/14596/what-specific-scholarship-is-there-behind-the-new-world-translation

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Several modern versions do capitalize Lord in Rom 10:13 such as NLT, NKJV, LSV, etc.

This is somewhat justified as the Rom 10:13 passage is unambiguously referencing Joel 2:32 as the OP has correctly pointed out.  That Paul is referring to Jesus as "Lord" in Rom 10:13 is beyond doubt; and the fact that he quotes an OT text referring to Jehovah/YHWH and applies it to Jesus shows clearly what he thinks of the status of Jesus.  This is not the only time this sort of thing occurs in the NT - there are other occasions where OT passages that refer to YHWH/Jehovah on the OT are applied to Jesus in the NT:

- Heb 1:6 quotes Deut 32:43
- Heb 1:8, 9 quotes Ps 45:6, 7
- Heb 1:10-12 quotes Ps 102:25-27 (LXX)
- Phil 2:10, 11 quotes Isa 45:23
- Matt 3:3 (cf V11) quotes Isa 40:3

One could extend this list greatly by including various exclusive titles of YHWH in the OT that are applied to Jesus in the NT such as:

- "**Savior**" Isa 43:3, 11, 45:17, 21; vs Matt 1:21; Acts 4:12; 2 Tim 1:10; Tit 1:4, 2:13, 3:6; 2 Pet 1:1, 11
- "**First and Last**" Isa 41:4, 44:6, 48:12; vs Rev 1:17, 18, 2:8, 22:13
- "**Lord of Lords**" Deut 10:17, Ps 136:3, 26; vs Rev 17:14, 19:16

... and many many more.

Answer (score 16):

In the old testament (and in many ANE cultures), "name" was a synecdoche for the person, but with the connotation that this is the mechanism by which the person was known. In modern English, we only think of "name" as an identifier with no relationship to the underlying character of the person, and thus many of these "name" references in scriptures are confusing.

Thus when the Angel asked Jacob, "What is your name?", this was not a request for identification, but the Angel was demanding that Jacob confess his nature, that is, that he was a supplanter, as Jacob means "supplanter".

A better sense-for-sense translation for modern readers might be "tell me who you are?" which would carry with it the connotation that this was about your character rather than just a mechanism of identification.

This is why it so profound that God changed the name of Abram and Jacob, as God is effectively changing their character from that point forward. It is a reference to an inward change. We are also promised to receive new names in Revelation 3.12, 2.17. This is also a promise of an inward change. See also Isaiah 62.2

> The nations will see your righteousness, And all kings your glory; And
> you will be called by a new name Which the mouth of the Lord will
> designate.

Similarly, to do something "in the name" of someone else was to take on that person's authority and character. Thus praying "in the name" of Jesus does not mean *saying* "in Jesus' name" as a magical incantation, but it means representing Jesus in the world as we pray, with his authority and character.

So with this background knowledge, if Christ plays the role of "davar" or Word of God, that is, the revelation of YHWH to the world, then to call on the name of YHWH would automatically require calling on Christ, as God's *nature* (i.e. his name) is revealed to the world *only as Christ*, and thus Christ's name would be the only "name" that *could* be called on if one wanted to call on the name of YHWH.

John 14.6-9:

> Jesus saith unto him, I am the way, the truth, and the life: **no man
> cometh unto the Father, but by me**. 7 **If ye had known me, ye should
> have known my Father also**: and from henceforth ye know him, and have
> seen him. 8 Philip saith unto him, Lord, shew us the Father, and it
> sufficeth us. 9 Jesus saith unto him, Have I been so long time with
> you, and yet hast thou not known me, Philip? **he that hath seen me
> hath seen the Father; and how sayest thou then, Shew us the Father**?

This passage in John, in the language of "names", says that Jesus was acting in the name of the Father, therefore to call on the name of the Father is  to call on the name of Jesus.

Acts 4.12

> Neither is there salvation in any other: for there is none other name
> under heaven given among men, whereby we must be saved

Comment: Ahh, excellent! - an answer that uses the ‘lens’ (foundation) of ancient near eastern culture to interpret text written within that context. +1

Comment: Thanks for an answer taking into account the culture of the time! In the verses near Rom. 10:13 (e.g., v. 9, 12), Jesus is referred to as "Lord" (Greek _kurios_, the same word that appears in Paul's quotation of Rom. 10:13), and in verse 13, we're told that calling on the name of the "Lord" (_kurios_) results in salvation. To confirm I understand, is the referent of "Lord" in verse 13 the same Person referenced by "Lord" in verses 9 and 12 (i.e., Jesus)? If so, then the referent of Joel 2:32's "YHWH" must be the same Person referenced by "kurios" in Romans 10:13 since it quotes Joel, right?

Comment: @TheEditor Yes, everyone at the time (that is, jews such as Paul) would consider Adonai, Elohim, YHWH, etc, as different names for the same referent, and the same for the Greek translations of these names.

Comment: Thanks! All this is quite helpful!

Comment: well said - be good if you brought that clarity to https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/63734/what-is-the-name-god-gave-jesus-john-1711

Comment: 'Name' שם also means 'reputation'.

Comment: So, what you are saying is that the name "Jesus" is the name that represents the authority and character of YHWH God? The name "YHWH" does not carry with it the fullness of the character and authority of God, as those have been fully revealed to us *solely* by the man Jesus, and hence, if one wanted to "call on the name of YHWH", that is, to trust in the character and authority of YHWH, one would have to trust in the character and authority of Jesus, as Jesus' character and authority is THE revelation of the character and authority of YHWH God to the world? Am I correct? +1

Comment: How does this even address the question of Joel 2:32 and Rom 10:13?

Answer (score 2):

Is Jesus being identified as YHWH in Joel 2:32 and Romans 10:13?

Joel 2:32a
New International Version

> And everyone who calls on the name of the **LORD** [H3068 Yahweh] will be saved;

Brenton Septuagint Translation

> And it shall come to pass that whosoever shall call on the name of the **Lord** [G2962 κυρίου] shall be saved

Conventionally, H3068 is translated as G2962.

Now to the NT in Romans 10:

> 9 If you declare with your mouth, “Jesus is **Lord** [G2962],” ...

This is the same Greek word that corresponds to the Hebrew Yahweh. In a sense, it says "Jesus is Yahweh". Not convinced? More contextual evidence follows:

> 12 For there is no difference between Jew and Gentile—the same **Lord** [G2962]

It says that the OT Yahweh is one and the same Lord of the Gentile.

> is Lord of all and richly blesses all who call on him, 13for, “Everyone who calls on the name of the **Lord** [G2962] will be saved.”

Now Paul directly linked Joel 2:32's Yahweh to Romans10:9a's "Jesus is Lord".

Is Jesus being identified as YHWH in Joel 2:32 and Romans 10:13?

Indeed, the evidence and linkage are strong. There is no doubt in my mind that in Paul's mind, they are one and the same in the context of Romans 10:13.

Answer (score 1):

One thing is for sure that Paul refers to Jesus as the Lord whose faithful invocation saves a believer, and that Paul interprets the Lord - JHWH - mentioned in Joel 3:32 as referring to the divine Hypostasis/Person of pre-Incarnate Christ, (as elsewhere he interprets the Lord leading Israel through Moses in desert (Psalm 68:7) as pre-Incarnate Christ (1 Cor 10:4)).

Another question is whether Joel himself refers specifically to the pre-Incarnate Christ, the second Hypostasis of Godhead, or to Father, or to Spirit. Since I believe Paul’s interpretation to be inspired, I deem it to be one of the plausible and theologically sound interpretations.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: not necessarily.

Longer answer:
Saying that passages like this equate Jesus with YHWH is a popular and common interpretation as evidenced by the answers here.  However, this isnt the only possible interpretation and it's not necessarily the best, in my opinion.  For example, here's what the late James Dunn says on the these two verses:

> Now in Joel 2.32 'the Lord' is obviously Yahweh.  But equally obviously in Romans 10.9-13 'the Lord' is the Lord confessed with the lips - 'Jesus is Lord.' The salvation of which Joel spoke is promised to those who confess Jesus as Lord.  He is the Lord upon whose name those who believe in Jesus call.  As already pointed out in Chapter 1, the fact that Paul thought of his readership in these terms is confirmed by his description of believers in the opening of his first letter to the Corinthians, as 'all those who in every place call on the name of the Lord Jesus Christ' (1 Cor. 1.2). The calling of which Joel spoke is a calling on God to exercise his saving power on behalf of the remnant of Israel. So the fact that Paul refers the same verse to the exalted Jesus presumably means for Paul either that Jesus *is* Yahweh,30 or, more likely, that Yahweh has bestowed his own unique saving power on the Lord who sits on his right side,31 or that the exalted Jesus is himself the embodiment as well as the executive of that saving power.

> 30. As Bauckham does not hesitate to affirm (*Jesus and the God of Israel* 193,196).  But if Ps. 110.1 allows the concept of two Lords, the second given his plenipotentiary status by the first, then there is presumably no reason why a passage like Joel 3.32 should not be referred to the second Lord (see the next note).

> 31. That God was understood to pass divine authority to others is indicated by the various individuals who were thought to play the role of heavenly judges - Adam and Abel (*T.Abr* . 11, 13), Melchizedek (11QMelch 13-14), Enoch and Elijah (*1 Enoch* 9.31; *Apoc. Elij.* 24.11-15) - including the saints themselves (Matt. 19.28/Luke 22.30; 1 Cor. 6.2-3). Cf. Hurtado's careful formulation: 'Early Christians saw Jesus as the *uniquely* significant agent of the one God, and in their piety they extended the exclusivity of the one God to take in God's uniquely important representative, while stoutly refusing to extend this exclusivity to any other figures' (*Lord Jesus Christ* 204).

(*Did the First Christians Worship Jesus? The New Testament Evidence*)

I like this interpretation very much.  It's honest, well researched, cautious, and dignified.  I realize many won't agree with it but it's worth considering.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply. To make sure I understand, is the explanation of James Dunn consistent with Jesus being "the LORD" referenced in Romans 10:13? Thank you in advance for your reply.

Comment: That's correct.  Dunn believes the Lord in Joel is Yahweh but the lord in Romans is Jesus.  I'll try to edit my answer to include that in his quote also.

Comment: OK I just expanded the quotation to include what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Calling on the name of Jehovah by going to Jesus is the same as going to Johnny to get answers of Betty, and Johnny being the power of attorney (POA) says I am she, ask me, not her.

It is the same as saying accept my son as the conduct you ought to be, or you do not accept me his father to be your father too. Your going thru Jesus to the Father is being seen as going to Jesus as his decision equal to the Father. But Jesus assures you he would say what his father would say. So it is like going to a POA that you can be assured is answering for the person he represents.

In all this heavenly imagination, what point you miss is that Jesus is replacing all the damn men, the priests, the kings, your boss, employer, doctors, and all the people who claim **they** are God for you. Jesus is saying do not be afraid to scrap all the humans and people who try to be your God telling you what is right, Jesus will show you, and forgive you when you don't see him correctly. The end matter is not your death, but the day a whole world stands returned from death saying this time we get it right.

Comment: Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics. Would you please mind unpacking what your saying? Am I right in assuming  that you do not believe Jesus Christ is the Lord being discussed at Romans 10:13? Thank You!

Comment: Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-can-we-educate-new-users-about-our-site-distinctives/803#803). I also recommend going through the [Help Center](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help)'s sections on both asking and answering questions.

Comment: Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics! Isn't Jesus the "Lord" of Romans 10:9-14? If so, then isn't Jesus the Lord of verse 13 specifically? This would mean that Jesus is the LORD (YHWH) of Joel 2:32 as well, since Romans 10:13 is a quotation of Joel 2:32. Do you see what I'm saying?

Answer (score 0):

There is no Jesus Christ in Yoel or in any of the ancient Jewish Hebrew and Aramaic texts.

Jews, not Christians nor Muslims, are the remnant of Israel. To say that Christians are the remnant of Israel is an antisemitic doctrine. This doctrine of Christian replacing Jews as citizens of Israel has been the motivation for the persecution and extermination of my people over the last 2000 years.

Greek is merely the translation of the original Hebrew,

Your style of correlation would be like saying

- Doctor Richard Feynmann was a doctor
- CNN Doctor Sanjay Gupta is a doctor
- Therefore Richard Feynmann too was a medical doctor like Dr Sanjay.

There is a misalignment between the meaning of the English word doctor between being used on Richard Feynmann and Sanjay Gupta.

The ultimate understanding of what the original Hebrew texts say must done by reading and understanding the Hebrew texts, not by misaligned Greek translations.

The Unique Identifier of Almighty is neither Yahuwa nor Jehovah nor Yahweh - those are Christian opinions. You must respect the Jewish opinions as the primary accepted thesis, because our ancestors are the originators of the ancient Hebrew texts.

The Unique Identifier of Almighty cannot be pronounced completely in verbal mode. To say that the complete pronunciation of the Unique Identifier of Almighty is yahweh is a pejorative. As a Christian, you will bear the antisemitic opinion that we have forgotten how to verbally pronounce the Unique Identifier. Saying that would be like accusing a software engineer of having forgotten how to pronounce a [GUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) like {adef-74be-face-d017}.

Some engineers might pronounce that guid verbally as "adef seventy-four be face doiz", for convenience' sake, but "adef seventy-four be face doiz" certainly is not the unique identifier {adef-74be-face-d017}.

For convenience our ancestors, like software engineers today, would take a portion of the pronounceable characters to associate a baby's new name to the Unique Identified. e.g.,Y'Hoshfat יהושפט, YirmiYahu ירמיהו .

Some people quote that the name yahweh had been used by other ancient tribes - to that I defend the sacred Name by saying - those other tribes copied from the ancestors of ancient Israelis. That phenomenon is mentioned in the ancient Jewish texts, where kings were afraid of the G'd of Avraham.

Therefore, you can only accept your Greek kuriou as an extremely inaccurate colloquial association to the Unique Identifier, just as "adef be face doiz" is an extremely inaccurate colloquial association to the actual GUID because when a system asks you for the entity id, the system will certainly and fundamentally respond to "adef be face doiz" with "Entity not found".

Jesus Christ is NOT, has NEVER been and NEVER WILL be the king of Israel. Or of Jews.

Answer (score -1):

**Is the name Ἰησοῦν "Jesus" in [Romans 10:9-13] equal to the Name YHVH from Joel 2:32?** - No.

In Joel 2:32 (English bibles) | Yoel 3:5 [MT], does the prophet יוֹאֵ֖ל Yoel tell Roman Christians (33-70CE) that they "shall be saved" יִמָּלֵט **Yimalet** (from keeping Torah) by calling on the name of Jesus? - No.

> [Joel 2:32 | **Yoel 3:5**] "And it shall come to pass that whoever shall call in the name of YHVH shall be delivered, for on Mount Zion and in Yerushalaim there shall be a deliverance, as YHVH said, and among the survivors whom the YHVH invites." ( וְהָיָ֗ה כֹּ֧ל אֲשֶׁר־יִקְרָ֛א בְּשֵׁ֥ם יְהֹוָ֖ה יִמָּלֵ֑ט כִּ֠י בְּהַר־צִיּ֨וֹן וּבִירֽוּשָׁלִַ֜ם תִּֽהְיֶ֣ה פְלֵיטָ֗ה כַּֽאֲשֶׁר֙ אָמַ֣ר יְהֹוָ֔ה וּבַ֨שְּׂרִידִ֔ים אֲשֶׁ֥ר יְהֹוָ֖ה קֹרֵֽא )

In the NT book [Romans], the apostle Paul reinvents Torah prophesy of [Joel 3:5] for Roman Noachide students of Yeshua the Nazarene - by stating a new prophesy in [Romans 10:9] :

> "That if thou shalt confess with thy mouth the Lord Jesus, and shalt believe in thine heart that God hath raised him from the dead, thou shalt be saved." ( 10:9  ὅτι ἐὰν ὁμολογήσῃς ἐν τῷ στόματί σου κύριον Ἰησοῦν καὶ πιστεύσῃς ἐν τῇ καρδίᾳ σου ὅτι ὁ θεὸς αὐτὸν ἤγειρεν ἐκ νεκρῶν σωθήσῃ· )

The apostle Paul in [Romans 10:13] misuses Yoel's prophecy in Yoel 3:5 to justify a new intercessory belief for Gentile Noachide students of Yeshua the Nazarene - to no longer observe Mitzvot of Torah:

> "For whosoever shall call upon the name of the Lord shall be saved." ( 10:13  Πᾶς γὰρ ὃς ἂν ἐπικαλέσηται τὸ ὄνομα κυρίου σωθήσεται )

Paul reiterates the revisionist philosophy of Yoel's prophecy in [Romans 10:4] to support the end of Torah Mitzvot :

> "For Christ is the end of the law for righteousness to every one that believeth." ( 10:4  τέλος γὰρ νόμου Χριστὸς εἰς δικαιοσύνην παντὶ τῷ πιστεύοντι )

Comment: In all fairness, the validity/authority of Paul's interpretation here hinges on the nature of Yeshua. If Yeshua didn't rise from the dead and didn't commission Paul as an Apostle, then yes this is absolutely a misuse of Yoel's prophecy - though it wouldn't really originate with Paul, it would more originate with Peter in Acts 2:36, where God's Spirit comes in power and Peter declares Yeshua as both "Lord and Christ". If Yeshua really did rise from the dead, then Paul is giving the correct interpretation of Yoel 3:5.

Comment: @SteveTaylor - In all fairness, does the prophet Yoel claim all inhabitants of Zion should repent to Jesus in order to be saved from keeping Torah?

Comment: No, but if we are under the assumption that Yoel is a genuine prophet then his words belong to God, not himself. The divine author is entitled to interpret and explain his own words to us, or to reinterpret them for a new purpose. Hermeneutically, YES it's important to understand and interpret Yoel as he would have personally intended or understood his words, but if Yeshua really did rise from the dead then we also need to consider interpretations of Yoel through that lens too. So it more comes down to what we believe about Yeshua, in which everybody is entitled to their own opinion! :)

Comment: @SteveTaylor - "Hermeneutically, YES it's important to understand and interpret Yoel as he would have personally intended or understood his words, **but...**" :) forget contextual answers - perhaps Paul understood Yoel's words better than Yoel.

Comment: Sure, it can be a tough choice in a question like this - either Paul's right and Yoel hadn't had the full extent of what his prophecy revealed to him, or Paul's interpretation is merely a human invention and he and all the other 'apostles' were frauds. There aren't many other options open to us.

Comment: The arguments Paul is making are absolutely standard mishradic exegesis. And are pretty rock solid compared to the wild interpretations coming from people like Rashi or even Rabbi Akiva. Rabbinical exegesis takes a missing "h", notes that it's gematria value is 5, and then concludes 5 items are missing. This is how the Talmud was written. So to complain about Paul here seems truly bizarre -- Paul was trained as a pharisee and is using conservative pharisee exegetical practices, much more biblically sound than what you read in the Talmud, for example.