# When Jesus died, did the Father and the Holy Spirit die with Him? At the resurrection did all three rise? Why don't we ask ourselves this question?

Tags: baptism

> Or don’t you know that all of us who were baptized into Christ Jesus were baptized into his death?

> We were therefore buried with him through baptism into death in order that, just as Christ was raised from the dead through the glory of the Father, we too may live a new life. For if we have been united with him in a death like his, we will certainly also be united with him in a resurrection like his(Romans 6:3-5)

If only Jesus died = HIS DEATH, only Jesus was raised = HIS RESURRECTION. Please, somebody, help me If Mattews 28:19 is about the baptism in the water then the Father and the Holy Spirit they die with Jesus and they were raised with Jesus?

Comment: There is a good reason we do not ask these questions - they are not addressed in the Bible anywhere.  Jesus died and was resurrected.  That is it.

Comment: The Son is not the Father, the Father is not the Son, and the Holy Spirit is neither the Father nor the Son. Three Persons share divine nature. The Father & the Son share the one, divine nature, with absolute unity of the Spirit in that nature. The Son incarnate died on the tree. His corpse was resurrected as proof that he is the sinless Son of God Rom.1:2-4. This is basic Christian doctrine. It is not logical to take that phrase about baptism to suppose it means the Father and the Holy Spirit died with Christ and were raised with Christ. All Christians know the Bible does not teach that.

Comment: Christians have often asked whether the Father also died, and the accepted answer since ancient times is a definite No. Theology questions belong on [christianity.se] however.

Comment: @david With respect, your question betrays a lack of familiarity with the scriptures. If you read large chunks of scripture, there’ll be gems all along the way that’ll point in the right direction. Two nice ones (there’s 3 or 4 on almost every page): Jesus forbade worship of himself post resurrection, reason being he had not yet ascended. The veiled/stripped nature of Jesus on earth is important; in Rev 4&5, Jesus is co-worshipped with God. Check it out, it’s profound. If you’re not from a liturgical church, note the high degree of similarity between worship liturgy for God and for Jesus.

Answer (score 0):

Jesus is, according to his own words, a man. He is not expressed as God anywhere so when he died, he remained dead until the Father, his God, raised him.

> now you are trying to kill me, **a man** who has told you the truth **that I heard from God**. John 8:40

Jesus is still a man - though a man with spirit, eternal life at God's side.

> For there is one God and one mediator between God and mankind, the man Christ Jesus. 1Tim 2:5

> He has set a day when He will judge the world with justice by the man He has appointed. He has given proof of this to everyone by raising him from the dead.” Acts 17:31

(Many think scripture says Jesus raised himself. It does not, but by reading theology into the text, it can be made to say anything. When striving to understand scripture with our own wisdom, we  mustn’t  generate conflicts with other scripture. Jesus raising himself, even though he was *dead*, generates many conflicts and is thereby rendered an invalid construct.)

The Father didn't die - He cannot die, He is immortal. He is the only being who is immortal. 1Tim 6:16 Some say the son is also God, but this is not of scripture.

Jesus was not immortal - that's why he could die. But once raised from the dead, God made him immortal too - unable to die anymore. Jesus was born of Mary about 2000 years ago as the [Gospels express](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/78007/why-don-t-unitarians-believe-that-jesus-christ-pre-existed-before-incarnation/78249?r=SearchResults&s=3%7C5.1499#78249). He did not exist before then except according to God's prophecies starting from Gen 3:15

> He was put to death in the body but made alive in the spirit. 1Pet 3:18
> We know that since Christ was raised from the dead, **he cannot die again**; death no longer has mastery over him. Rom 6:9

The [Holy Spirit is not an entity](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/53177/is-holy-spirit-the-spirit-of-the-father-according-to-luke-and-matthew/55619?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C73.3156#55619) that can die - it is the spiritual expression and power of God the Father just as His 'word' (logos) is. John 1 and 1John 1 (the logos isn't a person or entity either that it could die)

> All things have been handed over to me by my Father, and no one knows who the Son is except the Father, and who the Father is except the Son, and anyone to whom the Son wills to reveal Him. Luke 10:22

We see that if the Holy Spirit is part of a trinity, he would know both the Father and the son. This verse expresses the deepest intimate knowing that the Father and Jesus share - but no mention of the holy spirit. Many want to ignore this verse or read-in that which they feel is missing - we do not need to alter the word of God to fit our favourite theology. We are warned against doing so, but this hasn't stopped many from adding to God's word!

There certainly has been a lot of confusion over these matters. The bible is quite clear if we choose to accept what it says without reading-in additional to what  God has provided.

Only Jesus can die. He was born for this purpose and is the son spoken of in John 3:16

> For God so loved the world that He gave His one and only son, that everyone who believes in him shall not perish but have eternal life.

Regarding Matt 28:19. This is not talking about God dying, but through baptism, we may be joined to Jesus who died for all people. He died that we would not have to - speaking of a *spiritual death* not a physical death that all die. "we have been united with him in a death" as your passage expresses.

Conclusion: When Jesus died, only he died. The Father cannot die and the Holy Spirit cannot die either. We are baptised “into *his* death”, the bible states this unambiguously.

Edit: regarding baptism in the Q, no NT baptism was ever done according to Matt 28:19. It was always in Jesus’ name only. Yet, there is no downside to recognising the Father who also enabled salvation and the spirit by which we may live again as Jesus did. We can read in more to this than we should as this apparent *direction* was not followed by anyone being baptised by Paul or anyone else. The *name* represents the *[power of salvation](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/63734/what-is-the-name-god-gave-jesus-john-1711/67183?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C20.2662#67183)* which is from God and His son Jesus through the spirit of life.

> The works that I do in the name of my Father, these bear witness concerning me. John 10:25

Interestingly, the Holy Spirit has no name.

Comment: May our God and Father bless you, thank you, my question about Matthew 28:19 if the baptism is a symbol of death and resurrection of Jesus only then why do we do it in the name of the Father and in the name of the Holy Spirit when they never die, never were resurrected? Please help me with this!

Comment: Interestingly, no NT baptism was ever done this way, it was *always* in Jesus’ name only. Yet, there is no downside to recognising the Father who also enabled salvation and the spirit into which we may live again. We can read in more to this than we should as this direction was not followed by anyone being baptised by Paul or anyone else.

Comment: No NT baptism was ever done in this way?!?  It is how it was commanded!  Matthew 28:19

Comment: If it was a *command*, you would think the fledgling church would follow these matters exactly - NO ONE ever left a record of such a command being kept!

Comment: Matthew 28:19 look like is not in line with NT water baptism, if the water baptism is a symbol of the DEATH AND RESSURECTION of Jesus then why is there the Father and the Holy Spirit names when only Jesus the Son die and was resurrected ? Is it the work of the carnal mind and not the command of Jesus?

Comment: We don’t really know, all we can gather is, the Matt verse does not *seem* to be an error or addition. However, the practise of all those who baptised the early church was not to follow the Matt one-off direction. Jesus, as you say, is the one who died, and we with him, so his name is the most important. But Jesus came in the name of the Father, BY the spirit.

Comment: Thank you steveowen so very much!

Comment: You’re welcome, upvote or accepted answer also welcome:)